# How to select all foreign keys in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I have the following query for MS Sql Server,

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
              OnTable.name as OnTable, 
              AgainstTable.name as AgainstTable
    FROM sysforeignkeys fk
            INNER JOIN sysobjects onTable      ON fk.fkeyid = onTable.id
            INNER JOIN sysobjects againstTable ON fk.rkeyid = againstTable.id
```

Now I need to create a equivalent query in MariaDB. Basically, i need to know which are the tables in MariaDB to replace sysforeignkeys and sysobjects?

Comment: Check [Information Schema KEY_COLUMN_USAGE Table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/information-schema-key_column_usage-table/).

Comment: MariaDB's `information_schema` roughly correlates to `sysobjects`.  But good luck on matching things up.

Comment: Thank's @RickJames, as you mentioned `information_schema`correlates to `sysobjects`, I was lost in the docs and couldn't find it, the link you post here helped me a lot, case any new MariaDB user fall here, this link [MariaDB information_schema tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/information-schema-tables/) have every table of `information_schema`.

Comment: @WesleySilva - Yeah, that MariaDB page is good.  If you ever have trouble finding a MariaDB page, you could look in MySQL -- sometimes their pages are easier to find and/or more detailed; and _usually_ they have the same information.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
select
    fk.constraint_name, 
    c.ordinal_position,
    c.table_schema,
    c.table_name,
    c.column_name,
    c.referenced_table_schema,
    c.referenced_table_name,
    c.referenced_column_name
  from information_schema.table_constraints fk
  join information_schema.key_column_usage c 
    on c.constraint_name = fk.constraint_name
  where fk.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY';
```

Well, your query shows less detail. Here's the equivalent one:

```
select distinct
    c.table_name,
    c.referenced_table_name
  from information_schema.table_constraints fk
  join information_schema.key_column_usage c 
    on c.constraint_name = fk.constraint_name
  where fk.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY';
```